# How to disable VSCode auto installation of extensions for devcontainers

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm facing the issue that when using VSCode doing remote development with either GitHub Codespaces or on my machine using devcontainers; VSCode automaticially installs extensions based on what (features)[https://containers.dev/implementors/spec/#features] I have defined in my repository's `devcontainer.json`.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:ubuntu-22.04",
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/terraform:1": {
      "terragrunt": "none"
    }
  }
}
```

When I have terraform defined as a feature VSCode automatically installs the following extensions:

```
ms-vscode.azure-account
ms-azuretools.vscode-azureterraform
hashicorp.terraform
```

It is consistent across workspaces/environments.
I have no default extensions configured anywhere.

Does anyone know on how to disable this behaviour?